# Run source command using python and keep the environment intact for next set of commands

Tags: python-2.7, docker

I am trying to use subproces.Popen() to launch some command like below :

```
cmd = source /dev/stdin <<< "$(docker run --rm XX/YY-application:${APP_TAG} test)"

 proc = subprocess.Popen(
        cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True, executable="/bin/bash"
    )
```

Now it doesn't return anything, and even using `proc.stdout.readline()` returns me new line character. While running the same cmd, on the shell gives me proper output.

So, I have two issues:
1. why printing the stdout not giving me anything?
2. how can I save the environment created by cmd, to be used in subsequent command?

Comment: To question 1: Run the command with `set -x` turned on to see what is going on.

Comment: To question 2 : You could as last step inside your `cmd` perform a `printenv >env_file`, which dumps the environment to that file, and then in the next command use that file as a base to rebuild your environment. However, maybe you are better off redesigning your whole application, because it is an odd approach to carefully create a set of environment variables  in one process, and then, taking this as kind of a black box, recreate this environment in a different process.

Comment: so it should be "set -x source /dev/stdin <<< '$(docker run --rm XX/YY-application:${APP_TAG} test)'" ?

Comment: [`subprocess.Popen`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) explicitly takes an `env={...}` dictionary as a parameter.  You should use that and the array form of the command.  Trying to write a very complicated shell command, and then run that with `shell=True`, opens you up to some massive security risks (like rooting the entire host) and will be hard to maintain long-term.

Comment: As it is third party commands, I don't have control over it.  I am familiar with env, but not sure what needs to be passed to trigger source command.

Comment: @Rahul : Of course you have to place a statement separator, i.e. `set -x; source ....`.